# Save (store) list of simple objects on Android

Tags: android

I need to save List of simple objects

```
class simple{
String name;
byte[] data;
}
```

in android. How to do this ? Do I need SQLite or there is easier way ?

Answer (score 2):

Just refer serialization in java, and that makes your objects to be serialized.
see an example here,
http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_Serialization_Example_%28Java%29

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a database for that. It would make easier to get that data from different activities. [Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) is a great tutorial on dealing with database in Android.

I assume you can take that `byte` array as an `INTEGER` one for database type compatibility (or maybe some clever conversion to something else). The tutorial above provides you with info on the data types.